# Asking about convergence of a series in complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am trying exercises of an institute in which I don't study and I am unable to think why this particular series is convergent for $|z|\geq$1.

$$S_n(z) =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (n!)^{a-2r}\frac{ (k-rn+1)_{rn} (k+n+2)_{rn}} { (k+1)^a_{n+1}} z^{-k}$$

Edit - I am really sorry that I missed some details. $r$ and $a$ are integers satisfying $a/2\geq r\geq 1$ and $n$ belongs to natural numbers.

I have no idea which result I can use as both coefficient and variable $z$ have $k$ in it.

Can someone please help.

Comment: What are the indices $rn$ and $n+1$ doing here?

Comment: @Bernard it it poschammer symbol. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials

Comment: Decreasing factorial? But $a$ is a real exponent?

Comment: @Bernard please look at the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

As this is a power series in $\frac 1z$, you just have to find an asymptotic equivalent of the coefficient  $c_k$ of $z^{-k}$ to determine the limit as $k\to\infty$ of the ratio $\frac{c_{k+1}}{c_k}$, whence the radius of convergence for $\frac1 z$.

Now this is easy: as a polynomial is asymptotically equivalent to its leading term,
$$ (x)_{rn}=x(x-1)(x-2)\dots(x-rn+1)\sim_{x\to\infty} x^{rn}.$$

Comment: Sorry, I was revising results related to this question but i am now unable to prove how this series is convergent. Can you please explain the 2 nd paragraph of your answer and how to use it to prove convergence? the notebook where I wrote my explanation is not currently is not currently with me.

Comment: can you please explain?